# Html Table date loose on button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck in a situation

I am button click with some data. In the page there is a Html Table. In each row, I am loading status(Delivered/Undelivered)

There is a Send button when clicked it should update the status
Since the data is in Html Table I am loosing the data while Send button is clicked.
How do i resolve it.

Comment: Need more information. Is this a web forms or MVC project? Are you using gridview?

Comment: Are you aware that the nature of web pages and asp.net is stateless? That means each a request is made to a page, a new instance of your page class is constructed, controls are reconfigured (with the help of the view state to mimic windows programming), handlers are performed, and finaly page is rendered as html and released. The direct impact is that any local member of the page class is never preserved accross request. You 1st have to understand this model. Also, consider moving to ASP.net MVC. It's a bit more "raw" than webforms, but I strongly feel it's far more easy and cleaner to use

Comment: No ,Simple Asp.net Web project .I am using Html table.